# What php function to use when escaping strings inside arrays for postgresql queries

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a query that uses an array as follows:

`SELECT * FROM devices WHERE code = ANY ('{"value1","value2","..."}');`

If `value1` is instead `val"ue1` the query will fail. I can solve this by using a backslash before the double quote.  I'm trying to escape this using standard pg_ functions however `pg_escape_string`, `pg_escape_literal` or `pg_escape_identifier` don't appear to format the strings correctly.

- Is there a specific function to escape these types of array or do I
  just use write my own?
- Are there any better suggestions as to how I could write the query?

Ideally I'd like to use parameterized queries for this but it doesn't seem possible to pass arrays as parameters in pg_query_params()

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) says otherwise. *params - An array of parameter values to substitute for the $1, $2, etc. placeholders in the original prepared query string. The number of elements in the array must match the number of placeholders.*

Comment: But you can't assign $a=array() then do pg_query_params($conn,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=ANY($1)",[$a]);  php and/or postgres throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this modified version of the query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM devices WHERE code = ANY (ARRAY['value1','value2','...']::text[]);
```

Escape `value1` .. `valueN` using `pg_escape_string` and enclose them in *single* quotes.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the help.